# Show url image in the second VC with more quality and bigger size

Tags: ios, swift, url

**This code is in FirstView Controller -**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print("User tapped on image \(indexPath.row)")
        
        let myImageViewPage: MyImageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyImageViewController") as! MyImageViewController
        
        myImageViewPage.selectedImage = self.results[indexPath.row].urls.regular 
        
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myImageViewPage, animated: true)
    }
```

VC takes images from `results` array

Results is the array of `Result` struct which is

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let id: String
    let urls: URLS
}

struct URLS: Codable {
    let regular: String 
}
```

**Second View Controller**
This works in a similar way

```
class MyImageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    
    var selectedImage: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Download image in the MyImageViewController
        
        guard let url = URL(string: self.selectedImage) else { return  }
        
        downloadImage(from: url)
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: self.selectedImage) else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data , error == nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.myImageView.image = image
            }
            
        }
       task.resume()
    }
```

What can be a problem that does not open a image with bigger size in SecondVC?

I have searched everywhere and could not find because of Url Images which takes images from web.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Help yourself in finding out the difference between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to open a bigger image?  Is the downloaded file bigger?  Have you got a different UIImageView size?   Are you gettig any errors?  And if so what are they? There's not enough info here about what is downloaded or how it is displayed to allow us to help you.

Comment: @flanker I actually got no error and just watched youtube tutorial in order to show it in the new screen, and also applied it in my script but couldnt help me

Comment: @ElTomato In the Second view controller?

Comment: If you know the purpose of `viewDidLoad` in general, you would notice a basic but crucial mistake you are making in any view controller.

Comment: @ElTomato https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cawmiVPOFWY

Comment: @ElTomato I have applied same strategy in the  above link though

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you have.  Well, I hope your app is now working as your plans.  I'm not going to watch the YouTube video, though.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you ,  but i have done same thing , there is not enough change.  You mean i have made a mistake in viewdidload and viewwill appear?